# Is NP-complete complexity defined in terms of polynomial reductions or polynomial transformations?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np, oracle-machines

How do you know that a decision problem $X$ is NP-complete?, if all other NP-problems polynomially transform to $X$ or if all other NP-problems polynomially reduces (there exist a polynomial time oracle for any problem in NP using an oracle for $X$).

Definitions seem to differ all over the web.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Doc. I took the liberty of renaming your problem from $\mathcal{P}$ to $X$. I think things will get super-confusing if we're simultaneously using $\mathcal{P}$ to be a problem and P to be a complexity class!

Comment: "Definitions seem to differ all over the web" -- err, I hope not. Can you quote three different definitions?